# variable i might not have been initialized

Tags: java

`variable i might not have been initialized` と表示されるのですがなぜなんでしょう？
乱数を5個作ろうと思っているのですがなかなかうまくいきません。教えてほしいです。

```
public class Main
{
    static void getrandom5() {
        System.out.println ("Generating random numbers");

        int i;

        int nums[] = new int[5];

        nums[i] = (int) (Math.random () * (52 + 1));

        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            System.out.println("It is " + nums);
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[]args) 
    {
        getrandom5 ();
    }
}
```

Comment: English is also fine!  When I try to compile, it says "variable i might not have been initialized". I started learning java and this is my first question, so kindly teach me please

Answer (score 2):

変数 `i` が宣言はしたけど**初期化されないまま** `nums[i] =` の箇所で参照していてエラーになっていると思われます。

```java
int a;        // 変数の宣言
a = 0;        // 変数の初期化
int b = 1;    // 変数の宣言と初期化
```

参考:
[Variable might not have been initialized error - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2448857) の回答

Answer (score 1):

エラーの原因は、変数 `i` が初期化されていないのに読み込まれているからです ([@cubick さんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/59728/19110)と同じことを言っています)。

もう少し分かりやすくするために、プログラムへ1行ずつ、何をしているかコメントをつけてみました：

```
// 文字列を出力
System.out.println ("Generating random numbers");

// 変数 i を宣言 (この時点では初期化されていません。つまり、変数を読み込んだときの値が定まっていません)
int i;

// 変数 nums を宣言し、新しく確保した長さ 5 の配列で初期化
int nums[] = new int[5];

// 配列 nums の i 番目の要素に、乱数を代入 (ここで変数 i の値が定まっていないのに読み込んでいるため、エラーが起きています)
nums[i] = (int) (Math.random () * (52 + 1));

// i を 0 から 5 まで 1 ずつ増やしながらループ
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    // 文字列を出力 (ただしここで配列 nums の何番目の要素を気にしているのか書いていないため、想定と異なる動作をするでしょう)
    System.out.println("It is " + nums);
}
```

おそらく、元々なさりたかったのは変数 `i` を順番に増やしながら、配列 `nums` の要素へ順々に全て乱数を代入する、ということでしょう。であれば、次のように書きます。

```
// 変数 i を宣言し、i を 0 から 5 まで 1 ずつ増やしながらループ
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // 配列 nums の i 番目の要素に、乱数を代入
    nums[i] = (ここに乱数を生み出すコードを書く)
}
```